# access google ga var in dynamically loaded script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have dynamically loaded html and js and the html contains a button link (uses Smarty but not relevant to the question):

```
<tr>
    ...
    <td><button id="rid_{$roomRef}" type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="{$link}">&pound;{$rate|string_format:"%0.2f"}</button></td>
</tr>
```

each tr also brings in its own js:

```
$('#rid_{$roomRef}').click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

what I want to do is also add a Google Analytics tracking link like this:

```
ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘Supplier’, ‘Click’, $(this).attr('href'));
```

just before the window event but I get an error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: 
Unexpected token ILLEGAL jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
n.extend.globalEval jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
n.fn.extend.domManip jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3
n.fn.extend.append jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3
(anonymous function) jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3
n.access jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
n.fn.extend.html jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3
$.ajax.success (index):306j jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
k.fireWith jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
x jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
(anonymous function) jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
```

Any ideas on what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GA code has curly quotes. Note the difference between the quotes around the send/event vs the `$(this).attr('href')`

ga('send', 'event', 'Supplier', 'Click', $(this).attr('href'));

Comment: thanks. I just cut and paste it from a website without checking